# Invoking methods from another class ActionEvent parameter

Tags: javafx, netbeans

I am workong on a elevator and a elevator gui. 
In the fxmlcontroller class, I wrote all of the code. From our teacher we had to split it up into multiple classes. So I did.

The methods to move to a floor are in a seperate class now with paramater ActionEvent e. I splitted everything up and all looks fine. But when I invoke the methods in the controller class (Which is needed because at the moment the buttons don't work, they did before) it says it doesn't know variable e. I don't know how to invoke these.

These are the methods in the newer class:

```
public void moveToFloorZero( ActionEvent e ) {
        if ( motorDelta == 0 && motorD.getvDoor() >= 1.0 ) {
            if ( motorCage.get() < 1.0 ) {
                motorDelta = motorSpeed;
                motorC.start();
                floorIndicator = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void moveToFloorOne( ActionEvent e ) {
        if ( motorDelta == 0 && motorD.getvDoor() >= 1.0 ) {
            if ( motorCage.get() >= 0.0 ) {
                motorDelta = -motorSpeed;
                motorC.start();
                floorIndicator = 1;
            }
            if ( motorCage.get() < 1.0 ) {
                motorDelta = motorSpeed;
                motorC.start();
                floorIndicator = 10;
            }
        }
    }

    public void moveToFloorTwo( ActionEvent e ) {
        if ( motorDelta == 0 && motorD.getvDoor() >= 1.0 ) {
            if ( motorCage.get() > 0.66 ) {
                motorDelta = -motorSpeed;
                motorC.start();
                floorIndicator = 2;
            }
            if ( motorCage.get() <= 0.33 ) {
                motorDelta = motorSpeed;
                motorC.start();
                floorIndicator = 20;
            }
        }
    }

   public void moveToFloorThree( ActionEvent e ) {
        if ( motorDelta == 0 && motorD.getvDoor() >= 1.0 ) {
            if ( motorCage.get() >= 0.0 ) {
                motorDelta = -motorSpeed;
                motorC.start();
                floorIndicator = 3;
            }
        }
    }



    //
    //door motor imp
    class MotorDoor extends AnimationTimer {

        double vDoor = 1;

        @Override
        public void handle( long now ) {
            vDoor = motorDoor.get();
            vDoor += motorDelta;
            motorDoor.set( vDoor );
            if ( vDoor <= 0.0 || vDoor >= 1.0 ) {
                this.stop();
                motorDelta = 0;
            }
        }

        public double getvDoor() {
            return vDoor;
        }
    }

    public void openDoor( ActionEvent e ) {
        if ( motorDelta == 0 ) {
            motorDelta = -motorSpeed;
            motorD.start();
        }
    }

    public void closeDoor( ActionEvent e ) {
        if ( motorDelta == 0 ) {
            motorDelta = motorSpeed;
            motorD.start();
        }
    }
```

And this is the controller class, where I wanted to invoke the methods:

```
Floor0Button.setOnAction( gm.moveToFloorZero(e));

        Floor1Button.setOnAction( gm.moveToFloorOne(e) );

        Floor2Button.setOnAction( gm.moveToFloorTwo(e) );

        Floor3Button.setOnAction( gm.moveToFloorThree(e) );
```

Netbeans says: create local variable e. To be honest, I tried a lot of things but I cant find out how to fix it. If you need more information, then I can send you.

Kind regards

Comment: try `Floor0Button.setOnAction(gm::moveToFloorZero);` or `Floor0Button.setOnAction(e -> gm.moveToFloorZero(e));`

Comment: It doesn't give me errors at the left of the code.
But now I got an error message while compiling

Comment: These are lambda expression introduced in `java 8`. If you use an older version, you must make an anonymous instance of the `EventHandler` : `Floor0Button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        gm.moveToFloorZero(e);
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

I dont get an error any more. But now, when my GUI pops up, the buttons won't work. I can click on it, but there will be no animation seen. How to fix this? I tried many things, but since seperating everything, this won't work.